# ORACLE_HOME must be set and $ORACLE_HOME/dbs must be writable error in Xubuntu Linux 16.04

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, oracle-xe

Looking for some advice and help on issues, I am having with a new install of Oracle XE on my laptop running Xubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS. I followed [this](https://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.com/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html) post for my install.

In the Oracle XE install location `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/`
there is a `/bin` folder with a `createdb.sh` file I am trying to run to install the initial XE DB but am getting the error `ORACLE_HOME must be set and $ORACLE_HOME/dbs must be writable`.

My `.bashrc` contains the below code so I am not sure if it is correct and if it is, why am I getting the `$ORACLE_HOME` must be set error.

```
export ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe"
export ORACLE_SID="XE"
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE="/u01/app/oracle"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:."
```

In the terminal when I execute `echo $ORACLE_HOME`

I get

`/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe`

which seems to me like the path is set correctly. On to the permissions of the `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` directory.
`ls -l` shows this

`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  5 12:50 dbs`

which depicts the owner (root) has write permission. I am kind of lost on all of this and again, this is my first go round with Oracle SQL in Linux. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, all.

Comment: You need to add the environment variables to `/etc/bashrc` or `/root/.bashrc`. Your `~/.bashrc` only changes settings for you, not all users. So, when you run service, `root` user will not have `$ORACLE_HOME` defined.

Comment: @Munir. Thanks for the response. I followed your suggestion and set the same environment variables in /etc/bash.bashrc and rebooted but still, same error persists as before. Thank you and I will keep searching more.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww. Sorry if I asked in the wrong area. I have asked programming related questions here and thought this fit in a bit since it deals with config files, scripts and such. I will look at moving this to Super User. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute it as the oracle user. Do `su oracle` first and then execute the /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/createdb.sh